# Post_count only shows the number of results per page

Tags: wp-query, pagination, search

I have a wp_query `$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);` but for some reason the `$wp_query->post_count` only shows the amount of posts on each page. So if I set `'showposts' => '10'` and 12 results are found, page one will say '10 results found' and page 2 shows '2 results found'. Why is this? I can't figure it out.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post', 
  'showposts' => '10',
  'paged' => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
echo "Search found ".$wp_query->post_count."results";
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
// the loop
```

Comment: Have you looked at the variable `$wp_query->found_posts` as well?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`$wp_query->post_count` is supposed to work exactly like that. To get the total number of posts that exist in the database, use `$wp_query->found_posts`

Comment: ..and as simple as that, it works. Thanks so much guys!

Comment: I have a problem with this. When I filter results using found_posts - the number changes. I want to keep the static number of total results intact. How could I do this ?